# Searching especial character using grepl?

Tags: r, search, grepl

I have a data frame, and i want to find especial characters so i use:

```
 example$bb <- ifelse(grepl("*****", example$aa)==T, 1, 0)
```

But R says :

> ```
> Error in grepl("*****", example$aa : 
> invalid regular expression, reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'
> ```

Any suggestion?
How to do i write the symbol *****?

Comment: `grepl('**', '**', fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: In your first argument to `ifelse`, `grepl("*****", example$aa)==T`, you don't need `==T`, as `grepl("*****", example$aa)` is sufficient. Also, it is better to write out `TRUE` rather than abbreviate as `T`, since it is possible to overwrite `T`. So `T <-  FALSE` is a valid statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a meta character, use the escape meta character `/` to search for it

```
grepl('/*', '***')
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You need the backslash, not the forward slash. And you need two of them. The `fixed =TRUE` argument suggested by d.b. is preferable here, since the OP is searching for a bunch of asterisks. That would otherwise lead to a lot of escape characters.